# Not able to select date from date picker using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to select data from the calendar because it is not having the id's to select.

below is my HTML code,

[image]

[image]

The Code I tried is

```
 DateDOB = By.xpath("//*[@id='dob']")
strDateDOB="12/12/2020"
driver.findElement(DateDOB).sendKeys(strDateDOB);
```

but unable to select the date

Url to the application :

http://demo.guru99.com/V4/

username : mgr123
Password : mgr!23

Click on the New Account from the Left Pane to select the above discussed desired page.

Can any one please help in selecting the date?

Answer (score 1):

DOB has the `id`. sendKeys works. Don't use XPATH when ID is present.

I tried the following code and it is entering DOB value:

```
@Test
public void tst1() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mgr123");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("mgr!23");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Customer")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dob")).sendKeys("12/12/2018");
    sleep(5000);

}
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, Thanks for the reply, but it is not working for me :( iam using webdriver of 2.3.0  & java version "1.8.0_121" , Firefox 57.0 version.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I was able to solve by javaScript Executor method.  WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("dob"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
         
         js.executeScript("arguments[0].type = arguments[1]", select, "text");
         
         driver.findElement(By.id("dob")).sendKeys(strDateDOB);

Comment: 2.3.0 has support till Firefox 47 version. for later versions, gecko driver needs to be used. also, upgrade selenium to the latest version (>3 version). I am not sure they are still supporting FirefoxDriver in latest gecko driver and Firefox browsers.